# kafka Burrow reports Multiple Offsets for same consumer_group and same topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, linkedin-api, spring-kafka

**SetUp**

`myTopic` has a `single partition`.

`consumer_group` is my `spring-boot` app using `spring-kafka` client and there is *always* a `single consumer` for that consumer group. `spring-kafka version 1.1.8 RELEASE`

I have a `single broker node` in `kafka`. `Kafka version 0.10.1.1`

When I query a particular `consumer_group` using `burrow`, I see **15 offset entries** for **same topic**.

**Observations**

```
curl http://burrow-node:8000/v3/kafka/mykafka-1/consumer/my_consumer_grp
"myTopic":[
{"offsets":[
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099130556,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099135556,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099140558,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099145558,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099150557,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099155558,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099160561,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099165559,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099170560,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099175561,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099180562,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099185562,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099190563,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099195562,"lag":0},
    {"offset":6671,"timestamp":1533099200564,"lag":0}
    ]
```

**More Observations**

1. When I restarted the app again, I didn't find a new offset entry to be created, except the timestamp kept on updating; which is probably due to the `auto.commit.interval.ms`;
2. When I started producing/consuming; I saw the changes in offset and lag in one of the offsets; later on the other offsets caught up; which makes me think those are replicas;
3. `offset.retention.minutes` is default `1440`

**Questions**

- Why do we have 15 offset entries in `burrow` reports?
- If they are replicas, why does a single partition topic gets split up in 14 different replicas under `__consumer_offsets`? Is there any documentation for this?
- If they are *NOT* replicas, what else are they?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my understanding, based on [the docs](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/wiki/Configuration#Storage). Burrow stores a configurable number of committed offsets.  It's a rolling window.  Every time a consumer commits, burrow stores the committed offset and lag at time of commit.  What you are seeing is likely the result of having applied a Storage config something like this (culled from [burrow.iml](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/blob/master/config/burrow.toml)):

```
[storage.default]
class-name="inmemory"
workers=20
intervals=15
expire-group=604800
min-distance=1
```

Note that intervals is set to 15.
I believe this feature is simply to provide some history of consumer group commits and associated lags, and has nothing to do with replicas.

**EDIT:**

The [Consumer Lag Evaluation Rules](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/wiki/Consumer-Lag-Evaluation-Rules) page on the Burrow wiki explains this functionality in more detail.  In short, this configurable window of offset/lag data is used to calculate consumer group status.